# How to rotate CCUIViewWrapper view with cocos2D

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccuiviewwrapper

Using CCUIViewWrapper class in cocos2D for creating custom UITableView in my game.Problem is when game is rotating scene is rotating well but by table view is not rotating.

So , i want to know how to rotate CCUIViewWrapper view with cocos2D, perhaps in method like shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation for ios less than 6 and for ios6 shouldAutorotate.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the UIKit object isn't part of the cocos2D view, so when you rotate the cocos2D view, it is independent of the UIKit object.

I suspect that you could apply a UIView animation to the UITableView like:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25
                 animations:^{
  theView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
}];
```

Within the CCUIViewWrapper implementation you should be able to override the setRotation: message to apply the same rotation to the UIView it contains, and in theory they should stay in sync.

Just remember that cocos2D seems to use degrees and you'll need to transform this to radians for UIKit (or that's my recollection anyway).